# Should I write "it's just that he broke" or "it's just that he would break" in the following case?

Tags: grammar, past-tense

> It wasn't that my mother and I didn't care about Spike; it's just that he broke/breaks things faster than we could fix them.

**Over**

> It wasn't that my mother and I didn't care about Spike; it's just that he would break things faster than we could fix them.

What's the right form? (By the way, should I write *it's just that...* or *it was just that*? The sentence is in the past tense.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All are possible!

> It wasn't that my mother and I didn't care about Spike; it's just that **he broke things** faster than we could fix them -purely past event. He broke things faster...once...but now he *may not*.
>
> It wasn't that my mother and I didn't care about Spike; it's just that **he breaks things** faster than we could fix them -he *has* a habit of breaking things faster than you could fix it. The habit *was* there in the past as well!
>
> It wasn't that my mother and I didn't care about Spike; it's just that **he would break** things faster than we could fix them -'would' also talks about his *past habits*. Such constructions are common in storytelling *(say I'm describing my love... Mary and I would sit on the bench and enjoy the lovely sunset)*

**But** you said that the event belongs to yesteryear. So...it's in the past. Then let's make everything in past!

> It **wasn't** that my mother and I **didn't** care about Spike; it **was** just that he **broke** things faster than we **could** fix them.

Comment: I'm confused. I thought that I could write *It's just that* because it can also refer to the present. The fact (existent even now) is that at that time something happened. Like when you write *that's when he appeared*. Maybe I'm wrong?

Comment: I'm away. May get back once on computer

Comment: @ Maulik V OK, no problem. I appreciate that.

Comment: @Alexchenco, when you used wasn't and didn't instead of isn't and don't, you set the sentence in the past tense.

Comment: @ThePhoton What if the OP started the sentence with *It's not that* and *didn't*?

Comment: hey you accepted. Do you need any clarification? Do let me know then.